# Как регулярным выражением получить числа разделенные дефисом?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно из строки

```
https://mydom.com/recordings/sxqnplzmqzbhpgfe/xzconf350950vui351044naxz_2020-09-02-10-52-45.mp4
```

получить `2020-09-02-10-52`

Никак не работает регулярное выражение:

```js
var str = 'https://mydom.com/recordings/sxqnplzmqzbhpgfe/xzconf350950vui351044naxz_2020-09-02-10-52-45.mp4';

var arr = str.match("/.*(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}).*\.mp4/g");

console.log(arr); // NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = 'https://mydom.com/recordings/sxqnplzmqzbhpgfe/xzconf350950vui351044naxz_2020-09-02-10-52-45.mp4';

var arr = str.match(/_([\d-]+)-\d+\./);

console.log(arr[1]); // 2020-09-02-10-52
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
[\d-]+(?=\.mp4)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5bajc

> https://mydom.com/recordings/sxqnplzmqzbhpgfe/xzconf350950vui351044naxz_**2020-09-02-10-52-45**.mp4'

Answer (score 1):

1. Кавычки лишние.
2. Впрочем, `\` перед `-` тоже лишний, но он на результат не влияет.
3. Ну и нет смысла мэтчить всю строку такой регуляркой, достаточно просто фрагмента.
4. Флаг вроде тоже лишний.

```js
var str = 'https://mydom.com/recordings/sxqnplzmqzbhpgfe/xzconf350950vui351044naxz_2020-09-02-10-52-45.mp4';
var arr = str.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/);
console.log(arr[0]);
```